# Slow wifi on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, acer

I've recently dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10 on my Acer Aspire F15-571 (specs can be found here: http://www.laptopsdirect.co.uk/a1-refurbished-acer-aspire-f5-571-50s0-intel-core-i5-5200u-8gb-1tb-intel-hd-a1-nx.g9zek.001/version.asp?refsource=LDadwords&crtag=LD&refsource=Ldadwords&gclid=CKHp1u3Ync8CFQw6Gwods5kNYw). However, my WiFi is extremely slow - 1Mb/s. On Windows 10 it averages ~15Mb/s. I've tried different solutions like: https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ . However, this just disabled my WiFi (thus resulting in me reinstalling Ubuntu). Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Here's what pops up when I use: dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware

ii  linux-firmware                              1.157.2                                                     all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

Comment: same issue to me.